# Minimizing a WPF window owned by a Winform is not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, showdialog, winforms-interop

I have a `Form` control named `MyForm`, which is the parent of some WPF `BaseWindow`, named `MyWindow`.

I'm setting their relationship as follows:

```
new WindowInteropHelper(myWindowInstance).Owner = myFormInstance.Handle;
```

And am showing the window using

```
myWindowInstance.ShowDialog();
```

The window is set with

```
ResizeMode="CanResize"
```

Therefor, it has a minimize button. On minimizing the window, its not minimized as expected, but rather minimized to the bottom of the form.

What I would like to experience is that the parent would be minimized as well. Meaning that minimizing the window, will be translated to minimizing the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create event handlers to control their behavior relationship when events (minimize) occurred.

For WPF, you could use `Window_StateChanged` event with checking if `this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized`

Then for the `WinForm` you could do the trick by `Resize` event and checking if `WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized`

If any of these is true, then you could minimize both.